# How to set a SBT setting from Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, sbt

From the command line it is easy to set a String setting:

```
sbt 'set version:="MyVersion"' package
```

From Jenkins I call it this way (as a shell script snippet):

```
sbt 'set version:="$BUILD_NUMBER"' package
```

Unfortunately, the use of `'` prevents Jenkins from expanding variables.  SBT uses Scala syntax for literal Strings, and conflicts with the Shell.

Answer (score 0):

One solution (I don't know if optimal) is to use this:

```
version := System.getProperty("version")
```

and to invoke SBT this way from Jenkins:

```
sbt -Dversion=$BUILD_NUMBER package
```